# How to debug file upload in Rails 3

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2

While migrating an app from Rails 2.3/Ruby 1.8.7 to Rails 3.2.9/Ruby 1.9.3 I'm running into a problem with file upload to database. Not using Paperclip or Carrierwave gems (that's not an option, for legacy reasons.

In the controller#create action, where the uploaded file is received, the params hash has a string instead of the expected ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object.

The string is`"#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile>"`. So the upload fails b/c this string does not respond to #read.

The file is correctly being uploaded to Rails (looking at the browser timeline tools).

The middleware stack is identical to a fresh Rails 3.2.9 app.

I am at a standstill not knowing how to debug this. Between the incoming request and the controller, something is making a string out of the UploadedFile object.

Can anyone give me any clues where to look?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492730/how-do-i-introspect-things-in-ruby, perhaps?

Comment: not a duplicate, that question is unrelated, unless I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: What I was getting at is that you should introspect the create action and find out what line your object becomes a string.

Comment: I understand introspection of objects... how do you suggest introspection of a method? I have set the debugger in the method and I can see that the params hash contains a string iso an object, but I don't know where, before the controller, the object was created.

Comment: have the debugger, print the type of your object every line and you'll then realise where it becomes a String.

Comment: every line? The object is a string when it is passed-in to the controller#create method. I don't know where the object is created. That's where I'm looking for some insight.